# How do I setup a version control repository on a web hosting account?

Tags: version-control, web-hosting

I'd like to work on my own projects on different computers...on the road on a laptop, or at home on the desktop, or even at work.  I'd like to keep the data relatively private, and I don't want to pay for private repositories on github.

Ideally, I'd host a git or svn repository on my web host, or something like that.  Can I do that?  Or is there a web services-based version control system out there that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) for my development (svn).  You could also try [github](http://github.com/) (git obviously).

Comment: The OP did specify that he didn't want to pay for a private repository. Nonetheless, I'm voting up this answer because I think he needs to. And I also use and love Beanstalk.

Comment: I also use beanstalk. You can use any svn client (I recommend the excellent open source plugin AnkhSVN for Visual Studio), to connect, free single-repository accounts < 100MB, excellent speed, etc.

Comment: Oh - it's worth noting that a lot of free SVN services are only free for open source projects. Beanstalk has no such restriction, and is, again, free for single-repository projects that are less than 100MB.

Comment: It sounds like beanstalk is the winner, then, if it is free for non-open source projects.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I use beanstalk as well for about 2 months now, I'm very happy with it, it also has integration to lighthouse so I can close bugs/issues with commit to SVN.

I also have a local VPS server hosted and I installed the VisualSvn Server on it, it works great but it's a bit on the expensive side.

Answer (score 0):

My hosting provider, Dreamhost, provides Subversion repositories (along with Trac). However, if you can install a repository depends mostly on your hosting provider and what features they allow. Some make it easy, others won't allow you to install what you need to even set one up.